# Would the distribution of the average number of correct answers for a five-question game constitute an application of the central limit theorem?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, application

Say you have a game in which users answer five questions daily. Would the distribution of average scores for a single user among all of their games meet the criterium for the central limit theorem? I wouldn't think so but in practice it seems to be roughly normal. This could be a coincidence but I cannot think of a reason why it would not. Thanks.

Comment: So long as the scores each day had the same distribution and each day's scores was independent of other days (so a constant difficulty and no learning), the average score cumulated over time should follow the CLT (with its relocation and rescaling components)

Comment: I don’t see how that is relevant.  Five is not infinity and five is not going to increase in the poster’s design.

Answer (score 1):

Five questions a day means the score (assuming that is the number of correct answers) is an integer from zero to five. Whatever its distribution, it must have a finite variance, so there is no doubt the  central limit theorem will apply.

Even if there are some dependences between days, so the scores on different days are dependent, there are versions of the central limit theorem for dependent sequences.